# Ubuntu Gnome 17.04 customize file explorer

Tags: gnome

I want to customize the sidebar of the file explorer. My OS is Ubuntu Gnome 17.04, how can I add or remove things like "documents" or "other locations"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two answers to your question, because Gnome Files has two sections in the Files sidebar:

- The top section lists some of the default folders such as Home, Documents, Downloads, etc. This section is managed through a tool called `xdg-user-dirs` and a related configuration file located at `$HOME/.config/user-dirs.dirs`. To my knowledge, you can only really edit (show/hide) just these default folders. More information about `xdg-user-dirs` is [available here](https://freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/xdg-user-dirs/).
- The bottom section in Gnome Files is the bookmarks list. This is probably more what you want, as you can add locations to this list by permanently bookmarking them. For example, I have bookmarks to some of my most used network resources and local folders. To manage your bookmarks, watch this quick [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MOiZkGooIJ8).